# Lazy Loading modal windows, image in modal doesn't display

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, simplemodal, blazy

I am trying to lazy load images that display when clicking on a css based modal window. I am using blazy library and the image in the modal window isn't displaying.

Troubleshooting:

1. I confirmed the images load regularly
2. I switched out img src for data-src as required from
   http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/?ref=demo-page
3. Added the b-lazy class to the image I want loaded on modal window open.

```
 <div id="modalwindow1" class="modalbox">

 <div>
 <a class="closewindow" href="#close">X - Close Window</a>
 <h2>Business Name - Zebra paint job car</h2>
 <div class="container">

<data-src="images/zebra-car.jpg" width="1080" height="607" alt="Zebra paint job car"  class="b-lazy">

 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
<script src="blazy.js"></script>
<script>
var bLazy = new Blazy({ 

        //container: '#container' // Default is window
    });
</script>
```

I have a live demo of the above at

http://lidia.kaptlid.com/template1.php

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is missing the element name, `img`.

You have:
`<data-src="images/zebra-car.jpg" width="1080" height="607" alt="Zebra paint job car"  class="b-lazy">`

But you want:
`<img data-src="images/zebra-car.jpg" width="1080" height="607" alt="Zebra paint job car"  class="b-lazy">`

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, but then it loads all the images, checked in the network panel of firefox

Comment: There's no reason why it wouldn't load right away...  From what I can see of your source, the image is never hidden.

Comment: on my demo page its hidden with css

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option "loadInvisible" when you call Blazy to force load invisible images:
http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/#Options

Use it like this:

```
var bLazy = new Blazy({loadInvisible:true});
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to call Blazy when you open up the modal.

Good luck!